# get cookie from different place on same domain

Tags: php, cookies

I'm trying to show the username that is given by a cookie on my forum. Now the problem is that i have no idea how to get a cookie that is on the same domain but on a different location. 
Like the script is in `public_html` and the cookie is in `public_html/forum/`

I tried the normal way :

```
    <?php
$mycookie = $_COOKIE["member_id"];  
if ( isset( $mycookie ) )  
   print "<p>The value in cookie - $mycookie</p>";  
else  
   print "<p>There is no value in cookie.</p>";  
?>
```

but that gives a result of

```
There is no value in cookie.
```

So is there a way that i can receive a cookie on a different place or is this not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to store cookie for whole domain

setcookie("name", $example, time() + $time, '/', '.mydomain.com');